# session shows empty in other controller laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4

I have 2 controller `userController` and `ajaxController`

I have 2 session in `userController` like this,

```
public function getCheckout()
{
    Session::put('vouchers', array());
    Session::put('finalcart', array());
}
```

and i am puting more values in `vouchers` `session` like this using `ajax`,and then calling `calculateprice` method using ajax.

```
public function checkvoucher()
{
    Session::put('vouchers',$vouchers);
}
```

Now, when i am trying to retrieve session in `ajaxController` like this

```
public static function calculateprice()
{
    $finalcart=Session::get('finalcart'); // returns with values that i pushed in another controller.

    $finalcart=Session::get('vouchers'); // returns empty.
}
```

first i am calling `getCheckout` method then `checkvoucher`, when i am printing that session in `checkvoucher` then i am getting that proper. Then i am calling `calculateprice` which returns empty session. Its just taking old session values even after putting new value into session. I don't know where i did mistake.

Comment: Can you get the value of the session with the name 'vouchers' just after the line Session::put('vouchers',$vouchers) in the function checkvoucher() and share the output?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is actually an issue with L5.2 as any custom error pages display this error if you try to access a session based value (e.g a login form etc).

I assume this is because the exception does not pass through the web middleware group?

To resolve and prevent the 'Session store not set on request' appearing on my custom http error pages I moved:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

from the web group to the global middleware group in the kernel.php file which solved the issue.

So my kernel.php file now looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
   /**
    * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
    *
    * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $middleware = [
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   ];

   /**
    * The application's route middleware groups.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $middlewareGroups = [

       'web' => [
           \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
           \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
           \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
           \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
       ],

       'api' => [
           'throttle:60,1',
       ],
   ];

   /**
    * The application's route middleware.
    *
    * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
       'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
       'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
       'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   ];
}
```

If there are any better solutions I'd be glad to hear them as my grip on how to implement middleware is a little tenuous!

Comment: You shouldn't add session middleware to the global stack as it will also enable sessions for APIs as well. You won't need sessions in your API routes. Adding the middleware to the `web` stack would be better.

Comment: Probably because you're not adding `web` to your route group.

Comment: `code` Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {  \\all route define here  });   `code`